# Ubuntu 18.04 Updates override Nvidia Driver and cause display issues

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I've successfully installed the proper Nvidia drivers and everything works with my rig, but it seems that after system updates are applied, the Nvidia drivers stop working and all but my primary monitor stuck at 800 X 600 with no option to change it. As a quick fix, I can just reinstall the driver - but I basically have to do this weekly after system updates.

Here's my graphics card/driver info:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.39       Driver Version: 418.39       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P8     7W / 151W |    530MiB /  8116MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1972      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            34MiB |
|    0      2102      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          51MiB |
|    0      3039      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           280MiB |
|    0      3175      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         127MiB |
|    0      3713      G   ...uest-channel-token=13904980954611944284    33MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My suspicion is that when the system updates, it updates the build in graphics driver to Ubuntu and that takes over? Is there a configuration somewhere that I can change to always give the Nvidia driver preference?

I also have to assume that I'm missing important and relevant information to answering the question, so guidance as to what else is needed and how to obtain that info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what is "the proper Nvidia drivers", and how many of then have you installed. It is not recommended to install multiple Nvidia drivers, proper or improper regardless. Ubuntu has a special tool you should use to install the recommended Nvidia driver - yes, only one. For more info, search for Additional drivers. Install any other way, and you'll have to reinstall after every kernel update. I suspect that is the part you've missed.

Comment: Ok - that makes sense. I installed via the .run files that Nvidia provides to install CUDA so it's definitely not the method you mention. I know for sure I don't have multiple installed at least.

Comment: If I am not mistaken You will have to reinstall Nvidia Binary driver each time a kernel is updated. That's why I have updated kernel myself to the latest version `5.1.15` via mainline ppa and it stays that way as long as I want to. Just something to consider.